# How to get output of switch case and assign it to a variable and use it in another method of same class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a switch case and get the webElement output of the said case(s) and assign it to a variable to be passed as input in another method of the same class. I don't know how to go about this. My code is as follows

```
public class BaseClass {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebElement element;

///webdriver launched here

public WebElement findElement(String locator, String value) {

        WebElement element = null;
        
        switch (locator) {
        case "id":
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(value));
            break;

        case "className":
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className(value));
            break;

        case "xpath":
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(value));
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
            break;
        }

        return element;

    }


public void clickElement(WebElement element) {

        element.click();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(value));` should be `element = driver.findElement(By.id(value));` and the same goes for all the other cases.  Of course, you could use `return driver.findElement(By.id(value));` instead

Comment: It's a bit surprising that this even compiles. I don't think it would in C++. Java must introduce a scope per case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently redefining `element` in the `switch` block. You don't want to do that, just reassign it. Like,

```
public WebElement findElement(String locator, String value) {
    // WebElement element = null; // Assuming you want the `static` element.
    switch (locator) {
    case "id":
        element = driver.findElement(By.id(value));
        break;
    case "className":
        element = driver.findElement(By.className(value));
        break;
    case "xpath":
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(value));
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
        break;
    }
    return element;
}
```

Or eliminate `element` entirely and simply `return`. That allows removing the `break`(s) too. Like,

```
public WebElement findElement(String locator, String value) {
    switch (locator) {
    case "id":
        return driver.findElement(By.id(value));
    case "className":
        return driver.findElement(By.className(value));
    case "xpath":
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(value));
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    }
    return null;
}
```